# How to write and import Cmdlet inside Powershell script with C#

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to write cmdlet in c# just inside powershell script, so that I don't need to compile it myself, and also can leverage the WriteObject()/WriteError()  functions, but it doesn't work, anyone know how to do this?

```
$code = @"
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;

    [Cmdlet("Write", "Hello")]
    public class WriteHello : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position =0)]
        public  String Msg  { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            //WriteObject("Hello: " + Msg);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello: " + Msg);
        }
    }
"@

    Add-Type $code

    $cmdlet = [WriteHello]::new()
    # Error when invoke().
    $cmdlet.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please share errors messages:

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Cmdlets derived from PSCmdlet cannot be invoked directly.

It's obvious.

---

### Solution 1

Use `Cmdlet` instead of `PSCmdlet` if that satisfies your needs.

### Solution 2

```bsh
$code = ...
Add-Type $code
$WriteHello = [System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo]::new("Write-Hello", [WriteHello])
& $WriteHello -msg "abcd"
```

I recommend to compile the source code anyway. `Add-Type` is basically a wrapper of pre-installed "cscript.exe". It create a CS file in the Temp directory and compile it.

---

**Edit**

`Import-Module` from a source code.

```bsh
Add-Type $code -PassThru | % { Import-Module $_.Assembly }
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I use Add-Type to compile it to avoid manually compile after each time I modified it. Do you know if it is possible to register the Write-Hello cmdlet, so that I can directly invoke it by: Write-Hello -msg abcd

Comment: @xinglong I updated the answer. Please try after `Edit`.